# what's the difference between a form_for and form_tag object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

As the question says...What's the difference? When should each be used?

Here I'm using a form for, but could a form_tag be used alternatively?:

```
<%= form_for [@event,@comment] do |f| %> 
<% if @comment.errors.any? %>
<div class="error_messages">
  <h3>Please correct the following errors.</h3>
  <ul>
    <% @comment.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
<% end %>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.text_field :body, rows: 10, placeholder: "Leave a comment" %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit "Post comment", class: "btn" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form_for` is the right choice here.

From http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html:

"The form_tag helper accepts 2 arguments: the path for the action and an options hash."

Note that you can't pass it a model instance, like you've done with form_for, with `[@event,@comment]`

`form_tag` is basically just a convenience method which you can use to save yourself writing plain html.

`form_for`, on the other hand, accepts a model instance as a parameter, and based on that, provides an extra thing to help you - a parameter, `f`, gets passed into the block that you give it. `f` is a form object that knows about the model you passed into `form_for`, and makes writing the rest of your form easier.

See how you use `<%= f.text_field :body, rows: 10, placeholder: "Leave a comment" %>` later on in your form? You couldn't do that with `form_tag` because `f`, the form object, wouldn't be available.

Comment: That `f` is actually a [FormBuilder instance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html). The nice thing is that you can make custom ones very easily. The RailsCasts to this topic is unfortunately a pro episode but here is an example: http://www.likeawritingdesk.com/posts/very-custom-form-builders-in-rails

Comment: Or to put it short, you want to use form_for for your database attributes and form_tag for custom attributes that don't exist in your tables.